# Invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token on get request while using google classroom api

Tags: php, api

I am trying to use google classroom api following their documentation. I could get the results in the console but when I am performing a get request it give a 401 unauthenticated error. So later I implemented a google sign in in my web app but I still get this error. I had the bearer token in token.json file so I checked passing it with postman but still get that error. I just can't find the correct way of how I can use the oauth2 token to perform all requests.

I am trying this on localhost

I tried to pass the token in header with this code below

```
$tokenPath = '../token.json';
if (file_exists($tokenPath)) {
    $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath), true);
    $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
}

$token = $tokenPath;

$ch=curl_init($url);//the get request url i am trying to perform

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
   'Content-Type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer ' . $token
));

 $data = curl_exec($ch);
 $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
 return $data;
```

Someone who worked with it, please help me

Comment: Can you please add the relevant code to your question so others may see where the problem is.

Comment: ok i have included what i've tried so far. show me a way on how i can actually authenticate the request.